# How to input elements of Matrix in Python using List?

Tags: python

I simply want to take input in a 2D array(list), with dimensions n*m. For example,

1 2 3

4 5 6

1 2 3

7 8 9

for 4*3 matrix.

I want the input in the same format too. spaces between same row elements and 'Enter' between two rows.
New to python. have been searching for relevant soln. but didn't find any.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the repeated `1 2 3` line intentional?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're asking. Can you add a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), with the code you've tried to use, the actual result, and the expected result or output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May This one helpful for you:

```
n,m=map(int,input().split())
l=["0"]*n
j=0
for i in range(0,n):
    l[i]=["0"]*m
    l[i]=list(input().split())
print (l)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
arr = [[], [], []]
for i in range(4):
  for j in range(3):
    arr[i].append(input())
```

I did not try but it should work :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not already familiar with reading files in python, here's a common, effective way to do so. the with statement opens and closes the file for you. Then, loop through the lines and use the split() function, which will return a list of the line separated by spaces. Then simply append them to a list, resulting in your list of lists! The dimensions are not needed in the logic, so this code would work for any combination of dimensions.

```
with open('input.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
desired_list = []
for line in lines:
    line = line.split(' ')
    # if you want to cast the input as an int, 
    # use the line below instead
    # line = [int(x) for x in line.split(' ')]
    desired_list.append(line)`
```

Comment: Actually, I want to input matrix from the keyboard itself.